# Node Public Folder with AWS (amazon web services)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, directory, public

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy to direct traffic at my node app. When I go to my site, the jade view compiles and renders as html, but all my assets fail to load. I use node to set up a public folder where all my assets are like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Which works perfect on my local machine, but doesn't work at all when my app is on aws with nginx as a reverse proxy.

`xx.xxx.xxx.xx` works great, but `xx.xxx.xxx.xx/public` gives me an error page.

Comment: actually, it's normal; the /public isn't a route, it's where express will go get files if it can't find a view (static files). If you can access xx.xxx.xxx.xx, everything is working fine. to access /public/file.txt, just go to xx.xxx.xxx.xx/file.txt

Comment: That gives me an error as well. For now I'm storing resources in S3, but I'd rather have it function more like a normal machine...